# Pure swift set with protocol objects

Tags: swift, set, protocols

Is there a way to make the following actually work?

#### V1 - "test protocol does not conform to Hashable"

```
protocol testProtocol  {
    //
}

class test {
    var s : Set<testProtocol>?
    init(){
    }
}
```

#### V2 - "Protocol 'testProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

```
protocol testProtocol : Hashable {
    //
}

class test {
    var s : Set<testProtocol>?
    init(){
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that the answer is no - because protocols (even with the @objc tag) do not have enough information??  but maybe there is some sort of line or thing i'm missing here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps there is a better solution, but you can make your class generic:

```
protocol testProtocol : Hashable {
    //
}

class test<P: testProtocol> {
    var s : Set<P>?

    init() { }
}
```

Comment: But this means your set's objects will all need to share a class (or superclass), meaning you've added another requirement. Does this mean you can't create a `Set` in Swift of things that are *only* bound by protocol conformance?

Comment: @Zack: The problem is that Hashable inherits from the Equatable protocol which has a "Self requirement", in this case the operator `func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. Though I personally think it was a misstep in the language design of 2.0 to make `Equatable` require that the two items you were comparing were of the same class hierarchy. I've asked this question in the Swift dev forums at Apple, hopefully they will have a suggestion other than forking `Equatable`, `Hashable`, and `Set` to allow the comparison of items of different class Hierarchies.

Comment: @Zack: I cannot judge if that is a good design decision or not. Perhaps have a look at the "Protocol oriented Swift programming" WWDC session video, where something about the rationale behind this is explained.

Comment: I was actually in the room for that session :D

Comment: They do a good job of explaining a lot of the theory behind it. There are just a few things like this particular quibble where a big annoyance makes me nervous about using the rest of Swift which, as a whole, I find pretty excellent. I'm just hoping that if I wander around the internet enough I'll find someone on the team who can explain or change these decisions.

Comment: actually I just sat down and tried to rewrite `Equatable` to not be self-referencing and now have a better understanding of why it is. I think then the solution might be higher up in the language, giving developers a way to assert that all implementers of a Protocol will have to implement another protocol without making the Protocol self-referencing.

Comment: `Equatable` can be implemented without a `self` requirement. `Hashable` can not.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to wrap the set in a class or structure, and constrain the insertion function so that it only accepts items that conform to your protocol *and* to hashable. You can then use a `Set` of `AnyHashable` in the implementation.

For example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func doStuff()
}

class MyProtocolSet {
    var set = Set<AnyHashable>()

    func insert<T>(_ item: T) where T: MyProtocol, T: Hashable {
        set.insert(AnyHashable(item))
    }

    func iterate( doing: (MyProtocol) -> Void ) {
        for item in set {
            doing(item as! MyProtocol)
        }
    }
}

struct Foo: MyProtocol, Hashable {
    func doStuff() { print("foo") }
}

struct Bar: MyProtocol, Hashable {
    func doStuff() { print("bar") }
}

func test() {
    let set = MyProtocolSet()
    set.insert(Foo())
    set.insert(Bar())
    set.iterate { (item: MyProtocol) in
        item.doStuff()
    }
}
```

By putting the constraints on the insertion function, you're saying "this set has to contain things that conform to the protocol, and are hashable", without actually constraining the protocol to being hashable.

It would be even nicer if the wrapping set class could itself be generic, and take in the protocol to conform to, but I haven't figured out if that is possible yet!

Comment: Thanks!!! It really helped me. I'd only not force the casting at doing(item as! MyProtocol). Cheers

Comment: Great answer @Sam Deane. @Jeef this should really be the accepted answer. The currently accepted answer forces you to init with a particular class instead of allowing all heterogeneous objects that conform to the `testProtocol`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a `Set` (like the question asked for), but you can use an `NSHashTable` instead of a `Set`. You will have to expose your protocol to objc though. Although not a `Set`, if you're just looking to store a collection of protocol objects without having to conform to `Hashable`, this will work:

```
@objc protocol testProtocol { }
class Object {
    var s: NSHashTable<testProtocol>!
}
```

That way you can use the `add` and `remove` functions that are provided.

Furthermore, if you are storing observers or anything similar, you can initialize the hash table with `NSHashTable.weakObjects()` which will ensure the objects aren't retained.

Here's more about the `NSHashTable`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nshashtable

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution:

```
// make your protocol Hashable
protocol MyProtocol: Hashable {}

// use a Set with a wrapped value of concrete type AnyHashable (A type-erased hashable value.)
Set<AnyHashable>

// when adding your object, wrap it in AnyHashable
AnyHashable(someObject… conforming to MyProtocol)

// getting your object from AnyHashable
theAnyHashableElement.base as! any MyProtocol  // or as?
```

And so in the future when all of this Swift protocol nonsense is fixed, then you can just replace AnyHashable with MyProtocol.